# Logic for user session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

`user_signed_in?` method comes from the devise Gem. If a user is signed in, and there is comment, I want the `Delete Comment` link to appear. If there are no comments, I want the link not to be there. [Sample of show page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAxNV.png).

Here is the code:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <p><%= link_to 'Delete Comment', [comment.pic, comment], method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger", data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %></p>
<% end %>
```

I am having some trouble with the logic for the show page. If a user is signed in, the `Delete comment` link appears even if there are no comments. And if I post a comment, the `Delete Comment` link appears beneath every comment, with an extra `Delete Comment` link that is not linked to any specific comment.

Please help.

Comment: so where is `if there is comment` condition in your question?

Comment: Thats what I am having a problem with. Not sure how I would add that logic.

Comment: Well, you're going to see that link beneath every comment, because if you didn't, you'd be clicking delete_comment and not telling the application which comment you actually mean to target. Unless of course, you mean delete_comments. You'd have to write that method in your comments controller.

Comment: @Aaron I am fine with having the delete comment link underneath each comment. Thats what I want. The issue is that even when there is no comment, The Delete comment link still appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The delete link is showing up because you're not testing for the presence of the comment. You could do something like adding a test for an empty comment or if a comment exists:

```
<% if user_signed_in? && comment[:body].present?>
    <p><%= link_to 'Delete Comment', [comment.pic, comment], 
                   method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger", 
        data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I tried using that, and I get an `Undefined method, 'empty?'`

Comment: it should be `if user_signed_in? && comment.present?`

Comment: Still getting the same result.

Comment: What is comment? An object or  a string? Can you post the code where it is defined?

Comment: @jenstreetman its an object defined in my comments_controller `@comment = @pic.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:name, :body))`

Comment: So, just to make sure I understand, when you test if comment.present? When there isn't a comment,  the delete link still shows up? Or you get an error?

Comment: If the link is showing up, then the comment must be present, I'm guessing. Try testing if the body of the comment has something in it, !comment[:body].empty? Or something like that.

Comment: @jenstreetman Thanks! you solved it! i tried using the code you suggested and it threw an error, because of `empty?`, but I switched empty to `present?` and it worked.

Comment: I'm so glad. I'll edit my answer, and if you wouldn't mind accepting it, that would help me out. Thanks.

Comment: @jenstreetman This is so weird it. It was working fine then all of a sudden I am having the same issue.

Comment: I've been there. That is is so frustrating. Ca you post the code that you changed it to?

Comment: @jenstreetman ok it works again. So weird. I accepted your answer. If I have more trouble ill be in touch. Thanks again.